# Inverse of vector-valued function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction, inverse

Having a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\det D(f)$ (Jacobi determinant) does not vanish.
How can we get the **inverse function** $f^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that it can be handled/plotted/differentiated like we do for $f$?

`InverseFunction` does not cover this case. `NSolve, Root` are unsuitable.

E.g.:

```
f[x_,y_]:={2x+Sin[x+y],2y+Cos[x+y]}
StreamDensityPlot[f[x,y],{x,-3,5},{y,-3,5}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not perfect, but it is a start.

```
f = X \[Function] {2 Indexed[X, 1] + 
     Sin[Indexed[X, 1] + Indexed[X, 2]], 
    2 Indexed[X, 2] + Cos[Indexed[X, 1] + Indexed[X, 2]]};
Df = X \[Function] Block[{x, y},
    D[f[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 1}] /. {x -> Indexed[X, 1], y -> Indexed[X, 2]}
    ];

g = Y \[Function] Block[{X}, X /. FindRoot[f[X] == Y, {X, 0. Y}]];
Dg = Y \[Function] Block[{x, y, X},
    X = g[Y];
    Inverse[Df[X]]
    ];

StreamDensityPlot[g[{x, y}], {x, -3, 5}, {y, -3, 5}]
```

[image]

## Addendum

`FindRoot` can be very sensitive to the initial guess. By applying `f` to the points a sufficiently large and fine grid, one can employ `Nearest` to obtain a ``coarse inverse'' of `f` that can be refined with `FindRoot`:

```
ClearAll[f, Df];
Block[{X,x,y},
  f[X_] = {2 Indexed[X, 1] + Sin[Indexed[X, 1] + Indexed[X, 2]], 
    2 Indexed[X, 2] + Cos[Indexed[X, 1] + Indexed[X, 2]]};
  Df[X_] = Evaluate[
    Block[{x, y}, 
     D[f[{x, y}], {{x, y}, 1}] /. {x -> Indexed[X, 1], y -> Indexed[X, 2]}]
    ];
  ];

m = 100;
n = 100;
xgrid = Subdivide[-1., 3.5, m];
ygrid = Subdivide[-1., 3.5, n];
p = Tuples[{xgrid, ygrid}];
q = Map[f, p];
gcoarse = Nearest[q -> p];
ClearAll[g];
g[Y_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
  Block[{X}, X /. FindRoot[f[X] == Y, {X, gcoarse[Y][[1]]}]];
```

With `g[Y_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] :=` , I make also sure that `g` is evaluated only on numeric data. This should get you rid of most of the error messages.

I also added a few `Block`s in order to make things more robust.

Comment: Thanks! ``Plot3D[Norm[f[g[{x, y}]]-{x,y}],...`` looks good. Many warnings but except that.

Comment: ``Df`` is the inverse jacobian of $f$. ``Dg`` ?

Comment: `Df`  is the Jacobian of `f`. `g` is meant to be the inverse of `f` and `Dg` is the Jacobian of `g`.

Comment: Can we take advantage of the ``FindRoot`` option ``Jacobian``?

Comment: Yes, good idea!

Comment: Don't know why we get the message: ``The function value {0. -1. x,1. -1. y} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at {X} = {{0.,0.}}.``?

Comment: Well done, as usual!

Comment: Oh thank you... You are flattering me.